# Get ec2 dns name via pallet

Tags: clojure, amazon-ec2, jclouds, pallet

I get back a list of ec2 nodes using pallet. I want to get the dns names of these. I see that in jclouds there is a dnsName method, but I see no way to access this for use with pallet in clojure. Is this possible?

**Details**

I'm trying to make a modification to the storm-deploy project to work with dns names so that security groups work correctly. Specifically, I'm trying to write something like this function to use in the code:

```
(defn zookeeper-dns-names [compute name]
  (let [running-nodes (filter running?
    (map (partial jclouds-node->node compute) (nodes-in-group compute (str "zookeeper-" name))))]
    (map dns-name running-nodes)))
```

Comment: 0.7, though looking at the docs there doesn't seem to be support for this in 0.8

Comment: it's just not in the docs yet. My answer runs in 0.8 (i have not tested it in 0.7) the 0.8 beta is certainly ready for daily use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this in our pallet deployer which derives the dns name via the public ip:

```
(defn get-aws-name []
  (let [ip (-> (target-node) bean :publicAddresses first)]
    (str "ec2-" (apply str (replace {\. \-} ip)) ".compute-1.amazonaws.com")))
```

private IPs also work via security groups:

```
(defn ips-in-group [group-name public-or-private]
  "Sequence of the first public IP from each node in the group"
  (->> (nodes-in-group group-name)
       (map bean)
       (map public-or-private)
       (map first))

(defn public-ips-in-group
  "Sequence of the first public IP from each node in the group"
  [group-name]
  (ips-in-group group-name :publicAddresses))

(defn private-ips-in-group
  "Sequence of the first public IP from each node in the group"
  [group-name]
  (ips-in-group group-name :privateAddresses))
```

Comment: thanks. i ended up solving this using the private ips method.